# Do items vendors sell change over time?

Tags: path-of-exile

I noticed that when you create a new character, the vendors will sell you different items. Now that made me think, do vendors change items they're selling over time too (to the same character), or is their shop inventory different only for different players/characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merchant inventory is updated every time you level up since I recall it. Hint on the [offical forum](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/21808/highlight/) -haven't found anything more explicit, but I've been playing the closed beta for a long time.